# get CGPoint from coordinates of map OR get CGPoint from MKMapPoint iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, core-graphics, mkmapview, cgpoint

Hello for a navigation based application i need to get `CGPoint` from coordinates OR MKMapPoint of a `MKMapView`. I want to draw a line between these points but not a poly line.

I know all about MKPolyLine and other custom polyLines but due to some specific condition i have to get CGPoint from coordinates OR MKMapPoint..

I know how to get coordinates from CGPoint

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D touchMapCoordinate 
    = [mapView convertPoint:touchPoint toCoordinateFromView:mapView];
```

But i want reverse also.... I know how to get MKMapPoint

```
MKMapPoint  mp = MKMapPointForCoordinate(aCoordinate);
```

but dont know how to convert MKMapPoint to CGPoint. Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to convert co-ordinates to `CGPoint`, use below method

```
CGPoint point = [mapView convertCoordinate:location toPointToView:overlayView];
```

here location is `CLLocationCoordinate2D` object which has map `latitude` and `longitude` and `overlayView` is a view where you need to draw the polylines.